# Calculation on each cell of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

data1 =

```
Variables   A_0      B_0
Bins                                    
1           200      100
2           100      150
3           100      300
4           100      200
5           150      100
```

data2 =

```
Variables   A_1      B_1
Bins                                    
1           50       100
2           100      150
3           50       50
4           100      200
5           100      100
```

Now I want to create a dataframe that gives the percentage of cell values in `data2`, say for `A_1`, Bins = 1 has 50 value and for `A_0`, Bins=1 has 200 value, so the percentage becomes `(50/(200+50)) = 0.2`.

So the final dataframe that I want looks like below.

data2_perc =

```
Variables   A_1_perc      B_1_perc
Bins                                    
1           0.2           0.5
2           0.5           0.5
3           0.33          0.1428
4           0.5           0.5
5           0.4           0.5
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
data2_perc = pd.DataFrame()
data2_perc['A_1_perc'] = data2['A_1']/(data2['A_1']+data1['A_0'])
data2_perc['B_1_perc'] = data2['B_1']/(data2['B_1']+data1['B_0'])
```

Result:

```
    A_1_perc    B_1_perc
1   0.200000    0.500000
2   0.500000    0.500000
3   0.333333    0.142857
4   0.500000    0.500000
5   0.400000    0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

Make an empty dataframe

```
data2_perc=pd.DataFrame()
```

Then use following code to get desired output

```
data2_perc['A_1_perc']=data2['A_1']/(data2['A_1']+data1['A_0'])
data2_perc['B_1_perc']=data2['B_1']/(data2['B_1']+data1['B_0'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `rename` column of `data1`, `sum`, `divide` and last add [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
d = dict(zip(data1.columns,data2.columns))
df = (data2 / (data1.rename(columns=d) + data2)).add_suffix('_perc')
print (df)
           A_1_perc  B_1_perc
Variables                    
1          0.200000  0.500000
2          0.500000  0.500000
3          0.333333  0.142857
4          0.500000  0.500000
5          0.400000  0.500000
```